# Eclipse Ditto authentication

Tags: authentication, yaml, eclipse-ditto, ditto, eclipse-digital-twin

My issue is to change username and password in connection authentication of eclipse ditto. Usually, the default username and password was "devops" and "foobar". Now i have to change that default username and password.

I changed the default password by setting the environment variable DEVOPS_PASSWORD in the gateway service.

I need to know the way to change default username of connection authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The devops username is hard-coded at https://github.com/eclipse/ditto/blob/master/gateway/service/src/main/java/org/eclipse/ditto/gateway/service/endpoints/directives/auth/DevOpsBasicAuthenticationDirective.java#L38

So you can't use another username unless providing a PR for making it configurable.

Comment: I have one more question on configuring JWT authentication in ditto. i don't know on which config file i have to do and what i have to do? will you give me the steps how to do it? with one example.